# How can I assign a Windows drive letter to my "portable drive" (Samsung Tab 10.1)?

Tags: usb, windows, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drive letter for MTP connection under Windows](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/drive-letter-for-mtp-connection-under-windows)

There are a number of Windows file utilities I'd like to use to manage files on my device (Samsung Tab 10.1). To use them, I need to mount my tablet as a drive letter.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please be more specific with the Windows app you are trying to use. 1. Windows automatically mount if you're connected with UMS (USB Mass Storage) 2. Windows Explorer does great job of browsing file system without a glitch

Comment: The question is about assigning a drive letter. I can browse the files just fine.

Comment: Doesn't Windows automatically assign a drive letter if device is mounted?

Comment: No, it assigns is as a device *name*, not a letter.

Comment: Are you not using Windows Explorer to browse files? In almost all cases, Windows assigns letter.. See My Computer. Auto mounting on NTFS folder is not practical.

Comment: This should be asked on SuperUser.com, by the way.

Comment: @SachinShekhar:  don't see any particular reason this question can't exist here, since it's certainly an issue with using an Android device. Is it *also* appropriate for Super User? Perhaps, but that, in and of itself, doesn't make it off topic here. To the OP: I think the duplicate will cover what your issue is - the device is not getting a drive letter because it uses MTP rather than universal mass storage (UMS). Unfortunately, there is generally not a completely reliable way to work around that (especially if you're unrooted).