# Is there a way to connect Acer Iconia A500 tablet to windows PC via USB as a drive, not a device?

Tags: acer-iconia-a500

It currently shows up as a "device", but I prefer to have it as a drive so that I can run tools like SyncToy and many others against it.

Comment: Possibly related: [Drive letter for MTP connection under Windows](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22979)

Answer (score 1):

Download File Manager HD from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm.hd

Follow these instructions. Answer source: http://androidforums.com/2848952-post5.html

> On the panel at the left tap Storage.
>
> On the panel at the top right press the Up arrow until the first
>   directory entry is asec. Now scroll down through the directory and you
>   should see usb_storage. Tap usb_storage and you should see your data.

Comment: I want to access my tablet storage on a PC as a drive, NOT to see USB drive on the tablet (I am already able to that with similar file manager). The link and app seem to be doing the latter, no?

Comment: No.. sorry misunderstood your question. :S